# Aggregate symmetric pairs pandas

Tags: pandas

How do I aggregate symmetric pairs in pandas?

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
X    Y    count
A    B     2
B    A     1
C    D     5
D    C     3
```

My output should look like this:

```
X    Y    count
A    B     3
C    D     8
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same problem before , And this is my solution

```
df1=df[['X','Y']].apply(sorted,1)
df.groupby([df1.X,df1.Y])['count'].sum().reset_index(name='count')
Out[400]: 
   X  Y  count
0  A  B      3
1  C  D      8
```