# Aggregate symmetric pairs if they exist in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a dataframe

```
data = {
        "col1": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'], 
        "col2": ['B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A',],
        "count": [3, 7, 12, 2, 8, 2, 5, 9]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

col1 col2 count
 A    B     3
 A    C     7
 B    A     12
 B    C     2
 C    D     8
 C    B     2
 D    E     5
 D    A     9
```

I want to aggregate all the rows that have symmetric pairs while maintaining the rows that don't. Therefore, the output would be a new dataframe

```
col1 col2 count
 A    B     15
 A    C     7
 B    C     4
 C    D     8
 D    E     5
 D    A     9
```

I have looked at [Aggregate symmetric pairs pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373532/aggregate-symmetric-pairs-pandas) and [Find symmetric pairs quickly in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592606/find-symmetric-pairs-quickly-in-numpy) but neither of them particularly help me.

Comment: The first linked question does exactly what you want.

Comment: @QuangHoang When I do that, I get an error, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the given linked used `apply`, which generally is slow. Here's a solution with `np.sort`:

```
s = np.sort(df[['col1','col2']], axis=1)
df.groupby([s[:,0],s[:,1]])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  level_0 level_1  count
0       A       B     15
1       A       C      7
2       A       D      9
3       B       C      4
4       C       D      8
5       D       E      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Some small modifications to the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373609/6671176) does what you want:

```
df1 = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(sorted, 1, result_type = "expand").rename(columns = {0:'col1', 1:'col2'})

df.groupby([df1.col1, df1.col2]).sum().reset_index()

  col1 col2  count
0    A    B     15
1    A    C      7
2    A    D      9
3    B    C      4
4    C    D      8
5    D    E      5
```